# Using the eye dropper in a color type <input> breaks mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: html, css, input

Has anyone encountered this and know a html or css only workaround for this? It happens in both Edge and Chrome and possibly other browsers. Switching tabs makes the mouse wheel scrolling work again, but that's not a real solution ofcourse. The eye dropper tool is that pippet looking icon.

It happens everywhere, locally, but also in the snippet provided here and on e.g. [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvquhga1/14/).

```css
input {
  margin: 20px;
}

div {
  height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" />

<div></div>
```

Comment: Breaks scrolling how? Works fine for me

Comment: Likewise, no issues on Chrome or FF

Comment: @j08691 If you use the color picker, that pippet icon thing to copy a color, it still works for you? I just realised i poorly phrased the original question. So after googling i found out it's called an eye dropper.

Comment: The eyedropper tool that picks a color? Yes, now I see what you're saying, however after picking a color the scrolling seems fine

Comment: Yeah, normally picking a color is fine indeed, it was purely about the eye dropper tool i just did a bad job explaining what i meant.